# Plot clipped when saving with Matplotlib, but recovered when imported to Inkscape

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, inkscape, clip

I'm saving a plot using Matplotlib (3.6.2, with Python 3.9.12, Windows 10). Part of the x, y labels get clipped. To reproduce:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1.75,1.75), dpi=300)
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
fig.savefig("fig.pdf")
```

The plot in my PDF viewer:

[pdf-viewer-look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x95PC.png)

While I want it to look like:

[i-want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyaOd.png)

Then, I import the clipped image to Inkscape using the "internal import" settings:

[import-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZ4i.png)

and the clipped parts are recovered:

[inkscape-look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmjWW.png)

I don't understand what is going on behind the scene. Apparently, the clipped part is somehow stored in the PDF file, but not displayed. And Inkscape somehow can access this hidden data to import the full plot.

If I choose "Poppler/Cairo import", the imported image remain clipped, exactly the same as in PDF viewer.

I want to understand more about how files are handled, by either Matplotlib or Inkscape. Any idea is welcomed!

I want to see the plot in PDF viewer in the original unclipped form. In the Python code, I have tried not to use `plt.subplots()`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(1.75,1.75), dpi=300)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

but got the same result. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: Delete the `figsize=(1.75,1.75)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HMH1013! Indeed, I can get an unclipped image by removing `figsize`. But then what should I do to control the figure size, so that all the text in the image is in good size?